# Selecting similar words from mysql rows

Tags: mysql, aggregate, bigdata

how to select similar words or phrases from multiple rows in database?

What I have: about 100k products with titles

What I need: agregate similar products types - get most common title for group

There're a lot of various TV, clothes and all other stuff you can imagine.
Idea is to extract something like "Samsung TV", "Red dress", "Sunglasses" and so on. There should be some score to identify the relativeness (like score you get from match against in mysql).

Raw data for TVs example (it should come out as "TV Android"):

- LED Samsung TV with Android 36" and other features
- Another Samsung TV with better view 1.9m
- Widescreen TV with internet
- Panabonic TV with Android

Technology is not so important, it can be looped in php, java, node, mysql...

Any ideas how to do it? :)

P.S. It can be ported to elastic if it's easier..

Comment: What result do you want to receive? A table like "group" - "quantity"?

Comment: Result should be phrases for those groups. For example that phrase can be listed and after clicking it it would display search results from elasticsearch. This is something like keyword extraction. I think answering your question it would be group.

Comment: `SELECT product FROM table WHERE product LIKE '%TV%' ` ?

Comment: I need to cut down all unnecessary words like features and parameters and leave most common words. Your query just groups results. Titles are like in any other eshop with SEO stuff added into. Script should automatically decide what are the keywords and make new list. Bad example: foreaching all rows, then foreaching each title for separate word, and foreaching select/like every record and counting occurences. This will cause insane load and use a lot of resources... I'm hoping to find a smarter way :)

Comment: BTW your example requires manually enter LIKE '%TV%'. it should go without manual actions.

Comment: @neil-lun why you removed bigdata? :) This algorithm should be able to go through 15kkk records... Thats kind of big.

Comment: Why would it make a difference? Your question is about MySQL. It's tagged to MySQL. Generic tags are not needed, or generally helpful. We usually do use databases for lots of data.

Comment: `SELECT 'TV Android' as title, product as details FROM table WHERE product LIKE '%TV%Android%'`. But in this way you can't detect `Widescreen TV with internet`. There is no mention of Android. You should manually add some criteria.

Comment: The whole point is to do it automatically. I have no idea what data is available in database. It's too much to look through. Those phrases will be validated in the next step with something simmilar that you are using. This solution that I'm looking for is "thinking of" those words that you put in LIKE. E.g. SELECT name FROM table WHERE LIKE '%<THATS WHAT HAS TO BE GENERATED>%'; (btw there's better than using LIKE - MATCH AGAINST with fulltext)